# Как отследить нажатую кнопку?

Tags: java, android, android-on-click

У меня есть несколько кнопок. При нажатии на любую выполняется однотипная операция. Для каждой кнопки есть обработчик нажатия такого вида:

```
labirint11.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
             if(buttons[choice]==labirint11)
                labirint11.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.door_wall);             
             else
             {
                buttons[choice].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.door_wall);
                labirint11.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.door_go)                    
             }
        }
});
```

Я хочу менять картинку нажатой кнопки и той кнопки, которую случайно выбрал рандом. Нужно добиться изменения картинки каждой кнопки в каждом слушателе.

Вместо

```
labirint11
```

Нужно писать код, который будет получать идентификатор нажатой кнопки или что-то другое, не знаю. Таким образом я создам один обработчик на всех и добьюсь более упрощенного кода

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод `onClick(View v)` имеет аргумент коий и является нажатой вами кнопкой/картинкой etc. так что можете `labirint11` просто заменить на `v`

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
public void MultiClick(View v){
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.btn1: .... break;
        case R.id.btn2: .... break;
        case R.id.btn3: .... break;
    }
}
```

Не забудьте указать метод в разметке:

```
...
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/btn1"
    android:onClick="MultiClick" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/btn2"
    android:onClick="MultiClick"/>
...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
View.OnClickListener theOnlyOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(buttons[choice]==v)
                    v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.door_wall);

                else
                {
                    buttons[choice].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.door_wall);
                    v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.door_go);
                }

            }
        };

        for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
            buttons[i].setOnClickListener(theOnlyOnClickListener);
        }
```

Comment: спасибо, заработало)

Comment: не за что)  спасибо, @ЮрийСПб